# Timezone in Python for a list of cities

Tags: python, timezone, geocode

I have a list of cities for which I would like to extract the timezone. I am able to get the coordinates for each of these cities and I know the code to get the timezone for each of the cities individually. Hoping someone can help me loop through the cities in a dataset to get the timezones, so i don't have to do this exercise 540 times.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tzwhere and pytz for this.

```
import datetime
import pytz
from tzwhere import tzwhere


locations = {
    'New York': (40.7128, -74.0059),
    'London': (51.5074, -0.1278),
    'Paris': (48.8566, 2.3522),
}

tz = tzwhere.tzwhere()

for location, (lat, lon) in locations.items():

    # Get the timezone string for location
    timezone_name = tz.tzNameAt(lat, lon)

    # Get the timezone object
    timezone = pytz.timezone(timezone_name)

    # Get the current time in that timezone
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now(timezone)

    print(f'{location=} {timezone_name=} {str(current_time)=}')
```

The code above would print:

```
location='New York' timezone_name='America/New_York' str(current_time)='2022-04-08 23:54:38.077929-04:00'
location='London' timezone_name='Europe/London' str(current_time)='2022-04-09 04:54:41.271721+01:00'
location='Paris' timezone_name='Europe/Paris' str(current_time)='2022-04-09 05:54:41.279327+02:00'
```

Comment: beginning with Python 3.9, you shouldn't be using pytz anymore, you have [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) for time zone handling in the standard library. Also, from my experience, [timezonefinder](https://github.com/jannikmi/timezonefinder) is the better choice to resolve lat/lon to a time zone.